# Trouble analysing data set in R

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling

Hi I am having some trouble with the following;

So I have some data set, it contains an outcome of satisfaction , it also contains four predictors, 3 continuous , age, weight, height, and one factor predictor, either graduated high school yes or no.

So In R, I have uploaded the data set, and set $X1$ for age, $X2$ for weight , $X3$ for the factor and $X4$ for height.

I want to know if there is evidence that graduating high school has an effect on satisfactions.

But here are some things: I know that I can not simply look at lm(y~x3), because I need to consider all the other possibilities. So how do I take all of these into account? How many models must I check? What is the general approach to this?

I can do lm on diffirent models for example the full model, or the model just excluding x3. Do I just need to look for when $R^{2}$ values change?

Also, would I need to consider any and all possible interactions?
Any advice/general guidelines for this?

Comment: You will probably get more or better answers at the datascience stack exchange or cross validated, the stats stack exchange.

Comment: To be more helpful. You will need to think a bit about the situation. Do you worry about overfitting? If so then making an overly complicated model is probably going to be misleading, however neglecting key variables may also give a bad impression. Do you have a metric that you are targeting? Is your response continuous or is it a factor?

Comment: The response is continuous. I am not to worried about the over fitting, I just want to see if graduating has an effect on satisfication, or if it is really just all the other predictors

Comment: You should google 'multiple linear regression in R'. The _Quick R_ item might be enough. You can take all of the explanatory variable into account at once, and that item shows the syntax. Make sure 'HighSchool' is really a 'factor' variable; if not, use `as.factor` to convert. //  It is possible that some of the X's might not really be helpful. _Backward elimination_ is a method for disregarding unhelpful variables one at a time. _Forward selection_ starts with the 1 var with highest R-sq, then adds one at a time. Because of corr among the X's the two methods may not give same subset of X's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be decomposed into several pieces:

1. Make a hypothesis about what independent variable will highly affect the outcome of satisfaction, can you confidently include the these four independent variable. If the answer is yes, you can try a full model with four X's. If you're not quite confident, you can use [Likelihood ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test) to test different model with different variables.
2. Are they linearly correlated?  If the answer is yes(or you don't have any further information, for brevity, only use linear model), you can try the basic generalized linear model. In R, you can use "glm" to fit the model: $$Y=\beta_1 * X_1 +\beta_2 * X_2 + \beta_3 * X_3 + \beta_4 * X_4 + \epsilon$$
3. Goodness of fit, check $R^2$, t-test for each coefficient, F-test for whole model.
4. Build confidence interval for coefficients. And interpret your results.
5. If you're not satisfied with your model or forecasting power, there are two directions you can try.

   - add more interactions between independent variables.
   - try nonlinear model

In general, you can try all possible models if you want, but keep in mind, $R^2$ is not the only thing you should look at. You need more reasonable model rather than a high $R^2$ garbage.